How to create a customized navbar using angular fuse?
I am currently working on a project to convert plain Javascript to angular. The project is initially done using the admin lte 2.4 dashboard template. In conversion to angular, we're using Fuse template version 10.0. So the problem here is when the navbar is open, the content of the settings name should be available, and the sub settings will be in the list view. We can't able to get the exact version. In the fuse, there is a dense layout, which has the functionality of showing only icons when shortened. I need that, and in the thin layout, there is the functionality of showing the child items similar to the admin list. Here, I need these two in a new template.
I was trying to inspect and do the new template, but I don't know how to combine the above functionality into my new one because I am a beginner at angular and fuse. Any ideas and suggestions would help me solve this problem.
